# Does doFinally execute on the same thread in Reactor

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

Does doFinally execute on the same thread? Will below code block the main thread?

```
mono
.map(fileName -> asyncDownloadFile(fileName, folderName))
.doFinally(v -> {
    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(folderName); // this method is blocking
});
```

if so what is the best way to execute cleanDirectory in a separate thread in doFinally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the blocking call in a `Runnable` and run it on a separate `thread`:

```
Runnable task = () -> {FileUtils.cleanDirectory(folderName)};

Mono<Object> cleanDirPromise = Mono.fromRunnable(task);

mono
.map(fileName -> asyncDownloadFile(fileName, folderName))
.doFinally(v -> {
    cleanDirPromise.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).subscribe();
});
```

Note: This will essentially be a fire-and-forget call where you won't really care about the result of `cleanDirPromise`.

Comment: `Schedulers.parallel()` creates a fixed pool of worker threads as many cores as the running system. `Schedulers.boundedElastic()` is a better choice `creates new worker pools as needed and reuses idle ones. Worker pools that stay idle for too long (the default is 60s) are also disposed. ... This is a better choice for I/O blocking work. Schedulers.boundedElastic() is a handy way to give a blocking process its own thread so that it does not tie up other resources.`  taken from the documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers

Comment: `Schedulers.parallel()` should be used for highly cpu intensive tasks that needs to do computations on multiple cores.

Comment: and the `subscribe` should be removed there is no reason to subscribe in the middle of the application.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf doFinally does not subscribe to the inner stream. The outer subscription has nothing to do with inner stream subscription. As far as the scheduler is concerned, that was not a part of the question. But yeah, any blocking tasks need to run on elastic.

Comment: doFinally returns a Mono, so subscribing is not needed https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doFinally-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: @ThomasAndolf every Reactor operator returns a new stream, and so does doFinally. The inner stream has to be triggered by explicitly subscribing to it. You can try running a mock example. doOnNext returns a stream as well, but if you want to do an asynchronous operation in a reactive pipeline inside doOnNext, you still need to subscribe to it. Compare this to flatMap that implicitly subscribes to the inner stream. doFinally doesn't care about what you do inside it - You might as well run a CompletableFuture inside it.

Answer (score -1):

For this purpose is better to use `.then()` operator:

```
mono
    .map(fileName -> asyncDownloadFile(fileName, folderName))
    .then()
    .flatMap(
        Mono.fromRunnable(() -> FileUtils.cleanDirectory(folderName))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    )
    ...
```

Operator `then()` guarantees `cleanDirectory` will execute after `asyncDownloadFile`, also allows you build one pipeline and handle errors.

Comment: You also need to add your handler to error, but it better then run a new subscription in doFinally.